# How to declare a bean which has a constructor which takes String and Map as parameters?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor utility and passing the values thru constructor in called class. The constructor takes two arguments (1) a map (2) a string.

I am confused on how to declare a bean for the called class which takes two arguments( a map and a string). My code is as below.

```
***Calling Class***

    public class Starter {

        ProcessScheduler deleteBatch;
        public ProcessScheduler getDeleteBatch() {
            return deleteBatch;
            }

        public void setDeleteBatch(ProcessScheduler deleteBatch) {
            this.deleteBatch = deleteBatch;
            }


        public void start() {

        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = testThreadPoolExecutorService.createNewThreadPool();


            for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
            {
            Map m4 = arrayRecords.get(i);
            executor.execute(new ProcessScheduler("Thread #"+i,m4));                     // Comment - started 
The above line executes fine but it gives null pointer error if I will call any other method from the run() inside  called class(ProcessScheduler). So I have use a Bean such as executor.execute(getDeleteBatch("Thread #"+i,m4)) to get the instance of the bean. But I dont know how to do this in this case?

// Comment - ended


            }

***Called Class***



public class ProcessScheduler implements Runnable {

         public ProcessScheduler(String taskName, Map m) {
            this.taskName = taskName;
            this.deleteRecordsMap = (HashMap) m;
            }
        Processor processor;
        public Processor getProcessor() 
        {
            return processor;
        }


        public void setProcessor(Processor mappProcessor) {
            this.mappProcessor = mappProcessor;
        }


        public void run() 
        {
        // This returns null 
        processor.getNumbers();
        }

        }



I have some confusions as below.
(1) How to declare a bean for ProcessScheduler in this case. 
(2) Is the declaration of getDeleteBatch is correct in this case like below?

public ProcessScheduler getDeleteBatch() {
            return deleteBatch;
            }
```

Thanks
Gendaful

Comment: A constructor is easy. B constructor not always. C constructor, hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue as below,

From my calling class, I am passing the instance of Processor class in the execute method.

```
executor.execute
(newProcessScheduler("Thread#"+Thread.currentThread().getName(),hm,processor))
```

So, what it does is, since I am passing the processor as an argument in the execute(), it will not throw nullpointerexception if I call a method of processor inside run() of ProcessScheduler class.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really think this is a good idea?

```
public ProcessScheduler(String taskName, Map m) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
    this.RecordsMap = (HashMap) m;
}
```

I think it should be more like this:

```
public ProcessScheduler(String taskName, Map m) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
    this.recordsMap = new HashMap(m);  // You don't want changes to the Map passed in to show up in your private data member.
}
```

I'm not sure that you can inject ProcessScheduler instances from Spring as Beans; this might be a case where you really want to create a new one for each executor service.

Spring need not control every bean in your app.

Comment: hi duffymo.Actually, THanks for the reply. Actually,I am looking for how to declare the bean here. I dont know how to pass the values from one class to other class in constructor using bean declaration. And more importantly, the constructor takes Map and Spring as arguments, so totally confused :(

Comment: Ya. Completely true. If I will pass the value such as executor.execute(new ProcessScheduler("Thread #"+i,m4)) then it works fine. But if I will call anyother method from ProcessScheduler, then it will give null pointer exception.So, Bean Creation is the only way left i believe.

Comment: Can't tell why from what you posted.  Post the full class.  Bean creation may not solve your issue.  I can't tell root cause from the little you've posted.

Comment: Hi duffyMo, I have edited it with full code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

http://jonathanhui.com/spring-framework-xml-configuration summarizes the various ways of configuring spring beans and supported tags for instantiating and embedding collections.

Something like below should work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="processscheduler"
        class="ProcessScheduler">
     <constructor-arg  index="0" value="task1"/>
     <constructor-arg  index="1">
         <map>
              <entry key="key1" value="v1"/>
              <entry key ="key2" value-ref="someBean"/>
          </map>
     </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Hi Santosh,Thanks for the reply.Basically, I dont want to specify the value from applicationconfig file. I want to pass the values from Java class only. So the MAP and spring parameters from the calling class should be passed to Constructor.